# Getting SUM of row in MySQL with Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter

i am trying to find total of column of a Table.
I have a table call "tempbill". I want to find total of a column "total"
This code works fine. but it returns like ""[(Decimal('1812'),)]"" Where 1812 is the total number.
What should i do to get only 1812 as integer?

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter

import mysql.connector
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title('Stock')
root.resizable(width=True, height=True)
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(400, 400))
save_bill_btn=Button(
                root,
                text="Generate Bill",
                height=1,
                width=15,
                command="",
                highlightcolor="black",
                highlightthickness=1
                )
save_bill_btn.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=1,pady=1)

conn = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    password="",
    database="nc"
    )

c = conn.cursor()
data=c.execute("SELECT SUM(total) AS totalbill FROM tempbill;")
geydata=c.fetchall()
print(geydata)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: what does `print(type(geydata))` return?

Answer (score 0):

Simply Changing this line works for me
from

```
geydata=c.fetchall()
```

to

```
geydata=c.fetchone()[0]
```